# Design pattern for isolating parsing code?

Tags: c++, parsing, design-patterns

I have C++ class `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    [constructor, methods]

private:
    [methods, data members]
};
```

I want to add to class `Foo` the possibility for it to be constructed by reading data from a text file. The code for reading such data is complicated enough that it requires, in addition to a new constructor, several new private methods and data members:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    [constructor, methods]

    Foo(const std::string& filePath); // new constructor - constructs a Foo from a text file

private:
    [methods, data members]

    [several methods used for text file parsing] // new methods
    [several data members used for text file parsing] // new data members
};
```

This works, but I feel it would be better to isolate the new parsing code and data members into their own entity.

What would be an adequate design pattern in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: You could write the Parser as a separate class, and have Foo grant it friendship.

Comment: You could overload `std::istream operator>>(std::istream& is, Foo& foo)` and the *std::ostream* equivalent (not exactly construction though).

Comment: Agree about making the parser a separate class, disagree about the friendship part. I don't believe in violating encapsulation unless there is absolutely no other reasonable solution

Comment: If you need true clean code patterns you should not call in a constructor any system functions, like connecting to sockets, reading files, reading from STDIN and so on. Keep levels and responsibilities separate.

Comment: Also, parsing can fail, and it's often a bad idea to do something which can fail in a constructor. What's the result of constructing a Foo from a file with a syntax error? How do you communicate the failure to the caller? Throwing an exception is possible, of course, but that needs to be done with a certain amount of caution.

Comment: @cigien Thank you. I think this is a reasonable solution. If you promote your comment to an answer, I could mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Taekahn If the parser is not a friend of Foo, the problem is then that Foo must provide setters to the parser, for some of its data members, via its public interface. But then, those setters would be available not only to the parser, but to everyone else. Therefore, Foo granting friendship to its parser seems to be the lesser of the two evils.

Comment: @armagedescu Having construction and parsing happen in two different steps (via a constructor and a separate method) would complicate client code. What would be wrong in having the constructor throw an exception if something goes wrong (the file cannot be opened, parsing fails, etc.)? Exceptions exist precisely for this kind of situation, don't they?

Comment: @rici See my comment to armagedescu.

Comment: @user1387866 or provide a constructor that takes the values, and the parser returns the object calling that ctor, would be my preferred method. But there are 101 ways to skin this cat

Comment: @user1387866 in fact is vice versa. Mixing everything in a single functionality makes the code much more complicated, unscalable and by time it becomes unmaintainable

Comment: Parsing is always tricky code to maintain. Did you think of using a PEG for your input file's "language" (and the parsers are coded for you)? I haven't coded in C++ in a long time, but there are some solutions mentioned on https://bford.info/packrat/

Comment: @armagedescu Here, "everything", from the client's perspective, means one single parameter (the file name). If the client has first to construct a Foo, then call a separate method, this prevents the client from declaring the Foo as const (even if the Foo is not modified after parsing). Also, between (default) construction of Foo and the call to a separate method, the Foo instance would be in a default state. Whereas if everything happens in the constructor, you either get a fully constructed Foo instance, or (if an exception occurs) no instance at all - cleaner IMO.

Comment: @armagedescu Here is an interesting video about C++ exceptions: "Jon Kalb: Exception-Safe Coding in C++ (Part II)" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiZfODgB-Oc). From 0'58" to 9'37", Jon Kalb tells a story about throwing an exception from a constructor. Do you happen to be "the guy from the other team" ? :)

Comment: @user1387866 Hope googling helped you to ```read``` any fragments of that book. I am not going to argue about your ```reasoning```, because reasoning is not yet ```reason```. I will recommend you one more book "Robert C. Martin Clean Code A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship", which addresses the clean code patterns, and comes as a result of lots of code analysis. Is a very interesting book.

Comment: @armagedescu Thank you for the book recommendation. I read it many years ago, and I still have it on my shelf. Which section of the book are you thinking about?

Comment: @user1387866 section about levels of responsibilities in the code

Comment: @armagedescu Perhaps you mean Chapter 10 "Classes" (written by Jeff Langr), more exactly these subsections: "The Single Responsibility Principle", "Cohesion", "Maintaining Cohesion Results in Many Small Classes"? It would be hard to disagree with anything that's written there, and they don't contradict what Jon Kalb and other gurus say about throwing an exception from a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a good opportunity to use the so-called *Method Object* pattern. You can read about that pattern on various web sites. The best description I have found, though, is in Chapter 8 of Kent Beck's book *Implementation Patterns*.

Your use case is unusual in the sense that this pattern would apply to a constructor instead of a regular method, but this is of secondary importance.

Comment: This book has been on my list for a while, your answer will make it closer to the top of the list... After reading about "Method Object", I can see it is actually very similar to what @cigien was proposing. Since he didn't promote his comment to an answer, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot: **Thank you!** Thank you for answering the question I was asking, and for providing a useful solution to someone who was in need of a solution to a concrete problem, instead of lecturing about this being an "opinion-based" question.

Answer (score 1):

This is purely an opinion piece, so I'm surprised it's not closed yet. That being said... To me, it depends upon the format of your input file.

At my company, we use JSON representation for no end of things. We store JSON files. We pass JSON in our REST calls. This is pretty common. I have a virtual base class called JSON_Serializable with a `toJSON` and `fromJSON` method, and all the classes that are going to do this implement those.

I consider this 100% reasonable. There's nothing wrong with a class being able to serialize itself.

Do you control the format of your input file? Is it a format you're going to use a lot? If so, there's nothing wrong with making the class smart enough to serialize from a string.

Comment: @user1387866 That isn't true. I did NOT vote to close the question or I wouldn't have spent the time to offer one possible solution. I just know from past experience that opinion questions tend to get closed -- and I see there are currently two votes to close. Neither of them are mine. You asked for an opinion. I offered one. And now you're being rude.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a http server which involded parsing the request and response to something the server client recognized. Both fit builder pattern(https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder)

Heres a http example of request builder
https://bitbucket.org/ptroen/crossplatformnetwork/src/master/OSI/Session/HTTP/HTTP_Request_Builder.h
Their is also a response builder in same folder

Use case is similar your building something from or to txt file stream. But depending on the nesting of data could be more complicated so best to write requirements first